# GHCi could not load .dll lib (C++ lib) on Windows

Tags: c++, haskell, ghc, cabal

I've installed a C++ lib successfully via vcpgk, named: `lmdb:x64-windows`

I also installed [lmdb](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lmdb) binding package for Haskell by Cabal install

And when trying to test the lmdb package:

```
module Persistence where

import Database.LMDB.Raw
```

GHCi compiled and loaded it:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Persistence      ( Persistence.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Persistence.
```

But it throws error when I try to call any functions in lmdb Raw lib:

```
*Persistence> lmdb_version
ghc.exe: addDLL: lmdb.dll (Win32 error 126): The specified module could not 
be found.
ghc.exe: Could not load `lmdb.dll'. Reason: addDLL: could not load DLL
ghc.exe: C:\Users\thanhdo\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-
8.0.2\lmdb-0.2.5-1uQhV16mebP51rtMgitOcY\HSlmdb-0.2.5-
1uQhV16mebP51rtMgitOcY.o: unknown symbol `mdb_dbi_close'
ghc.exe: unable to load package `lmdb-0.2.5'
```

I was searching around and was trying several approaches but still can't resolve this error. I'm using Windows 7 64bit, Haskell platform 8.0.2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) about how DLLs are loaded. Make sure that your lmdb dll is one of the places windows looks for it.

Comment: What have you tried to fix it? Have you tried adding the directory containing `lmdb.dll` to the path?

Comment: I think cabal built success and module compiled with no error mean the C++ lib has no problem, and path to lib is Ok too. But got still got error in runtime.

Comment: That doesn't have to be the case, actually. Strictly speaking, the DLL doesn't have to available at compile time for the compilation to succeed.

Comment: @T.Do The purpose of a DLL ("Dynamic Link Library") is that it isn't necessary at compile time or at link time. It is only necessary at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As per discussion in comment section, I was trying to tell GHCi the location of lmdb's dll. It works after I modify %path% env.
In my case, the path was: vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\bin